# Catch error using catchError in a future and throw another type

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, catch-exception

I am not sure if this type of error handling and abstraction is done in a wrong way.

```
Future<void> _refresh() {
  return Future(() => throw someError)
       .catchError((error) {
         // maybe do something here
         throw abstractedError; //or even the same error
      });
```

Being able in another place to use it accordingly:

```
// in a widget/another place

void doSomething() { 
   _refresh()
     .then((_) => bla())
     .catchError((error) {
      //showSomeAlert() or handleSomething()
  });
}
```

Comment: You should wrap that in `try catch` block.

Comment: My issue comes when using mokito along with this pattern and it leads me to suspect that I have a wrong understanding for this.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad please recheck after my update

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I know I can wrap it in a trycatch but I was interested in using futures for chaining stuff.

Comment: @Durdu please edit your question, I just can't understand anything... make it clear

Answer (score 28, accepted):

We have in the flutter framework the description for the catch function:

> - Handles errors emitted by this [Future].
> - - This is the asynchronous equivalent of a "catch" block.
>       ...
>       Future catchError(Function onError, {bool test(Object error)});

---

When chaining futures I would advise against of using:

```
throw error;
```

and instead use:

```
return Future.error(SecondError());
```

This is because if you chain a future and expect to catch the error using the catchError future you will have the following problem.

```
Future<void> _refresh() {
  return throw Exception("Exception");
}

void main() {
    _refresh() // .then((_) => print("bla"))
    .catchError(() => print("not able to be reached"));
}
```

And you will get an error *Uncaught exception: Exception: Exception.*

This is similar when using RX (in general) and instead of throwing you send down the chain a Sigle.error (or any other observable with error).

---

**TLDR:**

When working with **Futures** and chaining them (including catchError) use **Future.error(Exception("Exception"))** to handle errors.

If you are using **throw** make sure or surround with **try catch** or **Future(() -> throw ... )**

Answer (score 29):

Your solution should work (simply `throw` another exception), but a more expressive way is probably to use `Future.error`:

```dart
Future<void> someApi() {
  return Future(() {
    throw FirstError();
  }).catchError((error, stackTrace) {
    print("inner: $error");
    // although `throw SecondError()` has the same effect.
    return Future.error(SecondError());
  });
}
```

and then use

```
  someApi()
    .then((val) { print("success"); })
    .catchError((error, stackTrace) {
      // error is SecondError
      print("outer: $error");
    });
```

You can play around with it at: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/8fef76c5ba1c76a23042025097ed3e0a

Comment: Thank you! I've also noticed that catchError returns a future and there doesn't seem to be any issue to throw an error from any future.

Comment: It seems that recently the only way you won't get an "Invalid argument(s) (onError): The error handler of Future.catchError must return a value of the future's type" is to use **return** instead of **throw**: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/?id=f82615e6202782a5b60a460827442ef7