# Return from Futures and catchError

Tags: dart, future

I would like to have the main function print StateB and not have an 'Uncaught Error' because of a type miss match.

I am not certain why this does not work as expected.

Here is the code from my [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/)

```
import 'dart:async';

abstract class State {
  String toString();
}    
class StateA extends State {
  @override
  String toString() => 'StateA';
}    
class StateB extends State {
  @override
  String toString() => 'StateB';  
}

void main() async {
  final result = await function1();
  print("Result:" + result.toString());   // <<<< HERE IT MUST PRINT StateB
}

Future<State> function1() {
  return Future(() => Future.value()) // some random task
    .then((_) => function2())
    .then((_) => StateA())
//     .then((_) => Future<State>.value(StateA()))  // COMMENT LINE ABOVE LINE AND SWITCH TO THIS ONE TO MAKE IT WORK AS EXPECTED 
    .catchError((error) {
      return StateB();
//      return Future<State>.value(StateB());   // COMMENT LINE ABOVE SWITCH TO THIS ONE TO MAKE IT WORK AS EXPECTED 
    });
}

Future<State> function2() {
//   throw Exception("function2");        
  return Future.error(Exception("function2"));
}
```

The way we re-throw errors also created a tricky situation. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596257/catch-error-using-catcherror-in-a-future-and-throw-another-type/55608201#55608201) for more info.

I've left some additional comments on the lines that actually make it work.

Maybe I missed something since in dart's documentation clearly they just return the value not a future with a value.

[Documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling) on Futures and Error Handling.

Comment: You say it doesn't work as expected but don't say what you expect.  What do you expect to happen, and what actually happens?

Comment: @jamesdlin updated