# Firestore : the error handler of future.catcherror must return a value of the future's type

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, error-handling

I have the code below that gets a document from Firestore from a reference, but if the get throws an error I get the following error "the error handler of future.catcherror must return a value of the future's type"

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot> getDocFromFirestore(
  {required DocumentReference ref}) async {
return ref.get().catchError(
  (onError) {
    onException(onError as FirebaseException, ref.path);
  },
);
```

What should be the return of catchError in this scenario?

Comment: have a look at this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55596257/catch-error-using-catcherror-in-a-future-and-throw-another-type

Comment: hey @Dreadclown, were you able to follow the suggestion above or have you find another alternative for solving it? if it is solved now then can you post the answer please.